# Which type of Hidden Markov Model is suitable for Speech Recognition and OCR

Tags: c#

I am using Accord.net hmm for speech recognition. But i am not sure if it is suitable for speech recognition or not and for me it is working very poorly. So, please tell me Which type of Hidden Markov Model is suitable for Speech Recognition and OCR. than latter i will try to find it in c#

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [htk](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/), its very easy to use, it's very accurate and modular and very fast. It's written in ANSI C, but I guess it's not difficult to interface into C#.